# mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

When I try to run this on my local server, I got this error:

```
mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

**connection.php**

```
<?php
require("constants.php");
//1:create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect("DB_SERVER","DB_USER","DB_PASS");
    if (!$connection){
    die("Database connection failed:" . mysql_error());
    }
//2:Select a database to use
$db_select= mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, "widget_corp");
    if (!$db_select){
        die("Database selection failed:" . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

**constants.php**

```
<?php 

//Database constants
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "helloworld");
define("DB_NAME", "widget_corp");
?>
```

Comment: define("DB_NAME", "widget_corp"); 
this line has been corrected as::
$db_select= mysqli_select_db($connection, "DB_NAME"); 
But still i have same problem

Comment: `(DB_NAME, "widget_corp")` that should be `($connection, DB_NAME)` and you cannot mix `mysql_` with `mysqli_`.